# What is the best HTML5 framework to do both Web AND Mobile applications with Java Spring

Tags: spring, html, mobile

I know there is already a lot of discussion here, but things change quickly and new frameworks are published.

I am looking for a robust HTML5 framework with which I can create both, Web AND Mobile applications if possible. I do want to create an application for the Web and Mobile (Android/iOS) and I do not want to use two or three different HTML frameworks.

On the server side there is Spring with Hibernate (Java EE application server). I know there is Titanium, Phonegap, GWT, Grails, jQuery, SpringMVC and much more. However I am not sure what to pick and if I could to Web AND Mobile with those. Actually I am not sure if it makes sense to look for one particular framework that can do both, but I assume from a learning perspective it might be right. I also know there is Adobe Flex which runs in a Flash Player on the Web and on Mobiles, but I do not want to use Flex (because of the Adobe announcement yesterday, I think Flex/Flash has not future on mobiles).

Ideally the framework should be well documented, robust and have a good community.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe MoSync is a good choice for you in MoSync you can combine HTML5 with C/C++. So you get the best of two worlds, HTML5 and native.